# How to calculate the weights and weight vectors of $Sym^n(V)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, representation-theory

I am wondering how to calculate the weights and weight vectors of $Sym^n(V)$

**note: I am working with in $\mathfrak{sl}_2$**

From my lecture notes, I know that the weight vectors  $Sym^2(V)$ are $v_j$ with weights $j=2, 0, -2$

And for $Sym^3(V)$ weight vectors $w_i$ with weights $i=3, 1, -1, -3$

But where do these come from? It seems that the maximum weight will be $n$ and they are symmetric about $0$

For example, I want to know how to calculate the weights and weight vectors of $Sym^5(V)$, my guess is that the weights would be $5, 1, 0, -1, -5$ or something similar...

Many thanks for your help

Comment: I'm guessing you are talking about $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ representations, where $V$ is the defining $2$ dimensional representation. Is that correct? It might help to say something to that effect in the problem.

Comment: @nate yes I am working in $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ , ill update the question accordingly

Comment: Have you tried computing how the matrix $\left( \begin{matrix} t & 0 \\0 & t^{-1} \end{matrix} \right)$ acts on $\mathrm{Sym}^n(V)$?

Answer (score 1):

Take the weight vectors in $V$ to be $x$ and $y$ with weight $1$ and $-1$, respectively. Then $\{x,y\}$ is a basis for $V$, so $\{x^iy^j:i+j=n\}$ is a basis for $Symm^n(V)$. The weight of $x^iy^j$ is easily seen to be $i-j$, which shows that the weights form an unbroken sequence of numbers starting at $n$ and going down in steps of $2$ to $-n$. In particular, for $n=5$, you get $5,3,1,-1,-3,-5$.